# How to write a moodle plugin that import and export course categories from one site to another

Tags: php, plugins, moodle

I'm looking  for away that i can export course categories and subcategories within a moodle installation to another new moodle site.

Is it possible to write a plugin that can do that in an automated fashion?

Your answer will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it already exists: https://moodle.org/plugins/tool_brcli

It's not 100% automatic because you need to execute a command to export from the source and another command to import to the destination, but it gets the job done.